# CSS - When scroll out page background isolate from site

Tags: html, css

i have some problem with my CSS , when i scroll out my page my background look terrible and isolate from site, can somebody help me to fix it?

my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    background-size 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Site can be found on: http://funedit.com/andurit/new

Thanks for read this :)

Comment: Could you clarify the issue please? What does "scroll out" mean? How is the background "isolated from the site"?

Comment: mate just go on a link i show and try to scroll out the site with your mouse scroll button :)

Comment: Add background-attachment: fixed; to the body. That what you want?

Comment: mate please don't post direct link to your site cause you question will become obsolete as soon as you will have fixed this...

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the navbar space as I don't see an issue. You may also want to center your background image with background-position: center 0;

Comment: @user3009924 - That space is caused by some bad HTML within your top-panel code I think. It's not really related to the background image changes I've suggested.

Comment: Sorry for that guys :)

Comment: I'll add my suggestions as an answer below. Please accept when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS-property `background-position` for your BODY tag:

```
body
{
    ... 
    background-position: 50% 0;
    ...
}
```

For add fixed-style for your background use CSS-property `background-attachment` as `fixed`:

```
body
{
    ... 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question previously in the comments but I'll add my answer here also. Add two new attributes to the body as below:

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center 0;

    background-image:url('images/background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    background-size 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
}
```